# Synonym proposal [spagobi] -> [fiware-knowage]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Direct from the [Knowage Documentation](https://knowage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> Knowage is the professional open source suite for modern business analytics over traditional sources and big data systems. **Knowage is the new brand for SpagoBI project**

Also:

> Knowage takes part in the FIWARE community, being the reference implementation of the Data Visualization GE.

at the moment the `fiware-knowage` tag has lower usage, but it should be the main tag going forward.

Since I haven't been answering in Knowage, I  can't make the change myself at the moment.

Comment: So... they're getting fiware in your spagobi?

Comment: what godawful names...